# Showing different error messages for different validators for reactive angular forms

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form in which I am using reactive form technique

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="contact">Contact Number :</label>
          <input  formControlName="phone" class="form-control" type="text"/>
          <span class="errorMsg" *ngIf="!signUpForm.get('name').valid && signUpForm.get('name').touched">Contact number must be 10 Characters long.</span>
          </div>
```

This is my input box for accepting contact numbers.
I have two validations for this input box.

```
phone: ['',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(10), Validators.pattern('dummyRegx')]],
```

Now I want to show different errors messages for regX failure or when length is not met. 
What will be the best way to show different errors for different validators.
Name of my form is loginForm.

So I am trying something like

```
{{loginForm.get('phone').errors.minLength}}
```

But I am not getting anyting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´m using like this

```
            <mat-form-field class="col-4">
                <input matInput [matDatepicker]="datainicio"  placeholder="De" [min]="minDate()" formControlName="datainicio_FCN" [(ngModel)]="anotacao.inicioVigencia"  >
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datainicio"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #datainicio></mat-datepicker>               
                <mat-error *ngIf="formularioAnotacoes.get('datainicio_FCN').hasError('required')">Data inicial é Obrigatória</mat-error>        
                <mat-error *ngIf="formularioAnotacoes.get('datainicio_FCN').hasError('matDatepickerMin')">Data inicial deve ser maior que a data atual.</mat-error>
                <mat-error *ngIf="formularioAnotacoes.get('datainicio_FCN').hasError('imcompativeis')">Data inicial e data Final são incompatíveis</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>


this.formularioAnotacoes = this.fb.group({
  filtroTipoSaida_FCN: ['', Validators.required],
  codigoProduto_FCN:  ['', Validators.required],
  documentoFornecedor_FCN: [''],
  titulo_FCN: ['', Validators.required],
  descricao_FCN:['', Validators.required],
  criticidadeSelecionada_FCN: ['',  Validators.required],
  datainicio_FCN: [null,  Validators.compose([  Validators.required, datasIncompativeis('datainicio_FCN','datafim_FCN' )])],
  datafim_FCN: [null, Validators.compose([ datasIncompativeis('datainicio_FCN','datafim_FCN' )])]      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Component class**

```
export class DemoComponent {
profileForm = this.fb.group({
firstName: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(10)]],
});

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
}
```

**Html**

First Name:

```
 <span class="errorMsg"
 *ngIf="!profileForm.get('firstName').valid && !profileForm.get('firstName').pristine && profileForm.get('firstName').errors.required">Require.</span> 

      <span class="errorMsg"
 *ngIf="!profileForm.get('firstName').valid && !profileForm.get('firstName').pristine && profileForm.get('firstName').errors.minlength">min 5 char</span> 

           <span class="errorMsg"
 *ngIf="!profileForm.get('firstName').valid && !profileForm.get('firstName').pristine && profileForm.get('firstName').errors.maxlength">max 10 Characters long.</span> 

{{profileForm.get('firstName') | json}}

 </form>
```